# How to remove lines that do not repeat enough times in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, delete-row

I have a matrix with one column like this:

NNN

NNN

NNN

AAA

AAA

CCC

CCC

DDD

DDD

DDD

I would like to remove all the lines in which I don't have 3 repetitions. This would result in removing lines 4,5,6,7 (and the result would be only the matrix with the remaining:

NNN

NNN

NNN

DDD

DDD

DDD

(PS: Those are strings, not numbers).

Is there an inteligent way to do that using matlab? I mean, using the functions and etc? Because I solved the problem with a for, but I think it is not the best way to do it and that it must have another way.

Thanks for the help in advance! :)

Comment: So this is a cell matrix that has one column of strings?

Comment: No, it is just a normal matrix with one column of strings and the other columns are many other things (numbers, strings, etc). I just need to use this column as the criteria to delete the whole line if there are not enough of these strings (as in the example). By the way, thanks for asking and for helping!

Comment: Is there a chance of finding four repetitions of something?

Comment: No, 3 would be the maximum. (actually 132 is the maximum, but I wrote 3 to simplify...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
t=tabulate(x) % count how much each element appears
valid=t(cell2mat(t(:,2))>=3,1) % find strings that appear at least 3 times 
result=x(ismember(x,valid)) % select only these strings
```

I assume here that x is a cell matrix with one column of strings. If x has other columns it is an easy fix.

Comment: Hey Bitwise, thanks a lot. I am having problems with the strings actually, because the matrix doesn't seem to be a cell matrix I dont know why. But you helped a lot anyway. I can already move on from here.
Thanks really a lot!